# logic and reasoning

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

My sentence:

> Sometimes a question can have multiple answers where all of them share some kind of evidence but none of them can be a [strict — right — 100% sure that it is the answer — what else?] answer.

Things that I have been thinking about but I do not want to use:

1. if the study of science is called *reasoning*, which means giving evidence (I am thinking of using "reasonable answer"). But reasonable answer does not mean that it is 100% accurate answer.
2. the word *logic* can involve math and philosophies, so it is not a word that I can use — because there is no "right" philosophy.

What else I can use for the word before the last in my sentence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "definite" and "definitive"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50343/what-is-the-difference-between-definite-and-definitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word **definite** fits your description. It means "absolutely correct", or the "one single" answer, basically.

Comment: I was about to suggest _definitive_ may be more appropriate and a preliminary search led me to [What is the difference between “definite” and “definitive”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50343/28951)

Comment: @Fortiter: For OP's question, the definitive answer is *definitive*. A *definite* answer is just one that definitely says something (usually "Yes" or "No"). A *definitive* answer is the one that everyone else recognises as correct, comprehensive, and conclusive.

Comment: @shnisaka, Another answer is "perfect", or "complete".